# delete duplicates from a list in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, filter, dropdown

hey there i am trying to display all of the options from my database in a dropdown,i have them displaying but i only want one of each result to appear and i cant figure out how to to get ride of the duplicates this is what it looks like when i click on the dropdown

[image]

here is the code to pull in the results

```
 void _getFieldsData() {
getUserDetails().then((data) {
  final items = jsonDecode(data).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  var fieldListData = items.map<User>((json) {
    return User.fromJson(json);
  }).toSet().toList();
  ///set list for class
  _selectedField = fieldListData[0].series;
  _selectedField = fieldListData[0].classs;
  setState(() {
       for (Map user in items) {
         _userDetails.add(User.fromJson(user));
        print(_userDetails.length);

         //if (_userDetails.classs != userDetail.classs.contains(_selectedText))
      }
     });
  // update widget
  setState(() {
    _fieldList = fieldListData.toSet().toList();
    //print(resultseries);
   // print(uniqueCount);
    print(_fieldList);
  });
});
```

here is the dropdown

```
                new  DropdownButton<String>(
                    hint: Text("Series"),
                   // value: null,

                    items: _fieldList.map((value){
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value.series,
                        child: Container(
                          width: 100,
                        child: new Text(value.series),
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear exactly what your User class looks like, but im assuming you have multiple fields that do not all have same values, for example, each with a unique id, that's why the following line isn't working in your case:

```
setState(() {
  _fieldList = fieldListData.toSet().toList();
});
```

i would suggest using [List.fold, List.any](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/List-class.html), and change the line above to check for only .series field, as below:

```
List initialResultsList = [];

setState(() {
  // use fold (similar to .reduce()) to iterate through fieldListData and return the updated filtered 'results'
  // list with each iteration:
  _fieldList = fieldListData.fold(initialResultsList, (results, currentItem) {
    // check to see if currentItem.series already exists in any item of filtered results:
    if (!results.any((item) => item.series == currentItem.series)) {
      // if not, add it to results:
      results.add(currentItem);
    }
    // return results for next iteration
    return results;
  });
}
```

Comment: hey there thanks for answering, how to i check for only .series as im a little confused

Comment: just like i did above, i updated the code and added comments for more clarity.